# Mongo lookup cannot access local field as the keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, lookup

here is my COMMUNITY COLLECTION JSON in mongo

```
{
_id : 6139cd4b37a3157a48154315
address : "johncommunity"

6139d1c637a3157a48154318 : {
date : "2021-09-09 09:21:16"
member : "john"
}
6139e78d37a3157a48154325 : {
date : "2021-09-09 10:56:07"
member : "mary"
}
}
```

and the other USER COLLECTION JSON is

```
{ 
_id : 6139d1c637a3157a48154318,
member : "john"
age : 28,
country : latvia
}
{ 
_id : 6139d1c637a3157a48sd43d8,
member : "mary"
age : 19,
country : germany
}
```

I want to use lookup and need to access all the documents from USER collection using the id(6139d1c637a3157a48154318) from Community collection using lookup
But how to access the keys as the local field?

```
{
  from: 'USER',
  localField: '<that specific key> . member ',
  foreignField: 'member',
  as: 'userId'
}
```

how do I write this changing key as in the local field?

Comment: Please provide valid sample data. What did you try?

Comment: fieldname-as-data is generally considered an antipattern since it isn't indexable and query support for that is spotty at best.

Comment: @Joe someone messed all this up  

Comment: The best option is change the schema.  The second best is use $objectToArray so the keys become values that the query can work with.

Comment: The sample data is still not valid JSON